Is there anyway to hook a KaiOS phone to a computer using Ubuntu?
The phone is a 'dumb-phone' I think that runs KaiOS 3.1. Its a tracphone made by Nokia. It can run primitive apps and even has a web-browser, though the latency is really bad. Plugging the phone into this Ubuntu computer does nothing (the OS is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS), same with a windows 10 laptop. From my research, this requires drivers on the computer to work. Windows supposedly has them natively, while Mac has ones you can download. I can find no evidence of such existing for Ubuntu or any form of Linux.
I can't get it to interface with anything. I'm plugging the cable into the port I normally put the charging cable in, because that and a headphone jack are the only ports it has (putting headphones into the headphone jack has never done anything either, I believe someone told me its for inputs not outputs). The only options it has for things like this is 'usb storage' (only connectivity options are wifi, cellphone data, and bluetooth). Enabling this does nothing, even if its plugged into either this machine or a windows 10 laptop when I toggle it.
I have no other devices I can plug the cable into to see if its the problem. Also, the phone doesn't try to charge through this cable. No idea if that's normal or not. When first plugged in, it doesn't light up either in any shape or form.
If it matters, I have a usb external harddrive I've been storing files on. I haven't had any problems getting that to work on this thing, minus its icon bugging out after initial load for some reason. I originally used it when the OS on this thing was windows 10. Other than the icon issue, it works just as before. Its cable is a standard USB to USB. The phone requires some micro-usb that I can't identify. I'm using a cable with multiple ends on it.

What are you trying to do with the phone? Access the filesystem of the phone? Use it for USB tethering? On android phones there is an option in the phone so that the phone shows up in the computer as an external storage/tethering device (and Ubuntu supports them out-of-the box, unlike Windows, where you may need to manually install drivers). Does your phone have these options?

I can enable 'usb storage', but turning this on seems to do nothing, even if I do it while its plugged in. No other options seem to exist. Its a tracphone made by nokia. I'm plugging it in through the port I normally put its charging cable into, because that and a headphone jack are the ports on the thing. I was wanting to write programs and put them on there, I would also like to be able to actually transfer pics and videos I make with my phone to a computer for once.

Can you please check if this works in Windows 10? We need to figure out if this is a Ubuntu issue or general KaiOS issue/USB adapter issue

Doesn't work on the windows 10 laptop either. I'll update the question with all this new information.

Does KaiOS have any forum where you can ask this issue? I suspect that this is really not an Ubuntu/driver issue

Also, the phone doesn't try to charge through this cable -- This does not seem to be normal at all. I suspect that the cable is faulty.

Well, how can I identify the end? Its not labeled. All I know its the same micro usb the charger uses. I have no way to idenify what the phone is precisely. Its actually an updated version of my previous phone that oddly enough was made by verizon. I don't get that considering the differences between the phones are minimal.

Uh, what do you mean 'problem can't be reproduced'. I tested it multiple times, and it consistently failed until I got the new cable, the it worked consistently. How is that not reproducible? What, do all my questions just get closed no matter what I type? Its over whelmingly obvious this post meets the requirements. Am I just not allowed to post on here? I'm getting sick of being banned due to all my questions getting closed completely regardless of what they are.

Well, I wasn't aware of that at the time. I thought it was a computer issue. Is it my fault that didn't turn out to be the case? Granted, I could've checked on my laptop first. Still, KaiOS doesn't seem to have a dedicated board anywhere, so a linux board is probably the next best place.

Please don't be offended if your question is closed. It does not mean you were at fault. After all, you were having an issue, and we were able to come up with a solution. This site is about Ubuntu (it is not a generic Linux/KaiOS site), and your problem eventually turned out to be not an Ubuntu problem.

It is a problem when you get permabanned from boards here for posting 'too many stupid questions'. So yes, I do care, especially here since I'm still new to linux.

You have asked only one question so far. That getting closed does not count as "too many", and it should not do anything like banning your account.

So, asking for clarification on a rule, or how their definition of 'subjective' doesn't line up with the rest of the world, is 'subjective'? This site literally thinks asking what 2+2 equals is 'subjective'. So yeah, banned again, and I can't do a damned thing about it. I don't even know how long my ban will last this time; I never got any message, I was only told it after I typed a question and tried to submit it. Guess I'm now permanently banned? Fuck my life.

I have no idea what you are talking about. I can see that you have only asked a single question. This is not a math site either. Also, please note that using profane language is not allowed on this site. Please read https://askubuntu.com/conduct

Actually, I've been banned on the 'main' website. It would seem this is distinct, since logging in here doesn't make you logged in over there, or vice versa. Still, I'm forever banned from posting. It doesn't give me a date when I can post again; it just tells me I need to post from another location. So, I'm not allowed to post again until I change address? Bullshit. What type of rule is that? How would that block problematic users? Are they just acknowledging that ip banning someone isn't fully permanent? I need to just stop posting onine. When does my questions ever get answered?

Why should I even trust the internet? This one question here worked, yes, but that's ultra rare. I need to just stop using the internet to avoid misinformation. As for the cable, I did find a usb wall socket thing I could've used to test it later. This means I may have been able to deduce on my own that the cable was faulty. If I could've solved this question on my own all along, what use is the internet? Guess I'll have to learn to play minecraft completely on my own now. You're not allowed to ask questions about it ANYWHERE.

Simply acknowledging the game exists seems to be worthy of a perma ip ban. Is the game that hated? Can I never even so much as look it up again. Will looking it up put me on a watch list? That's how everybody seems to be acting. Bye Forever/

I bought a new cable as per the comments suggestions. An employee told me it is a usb-c cable. Everything works fine now. The phone lights up when I plug it in, it charges, and I am even able to open its folders on my computer now.
A faulty cable was the problem all along. Thanks for the help.
